# Infopath Form Template Publish Permission For a Site Collection Admin

Tags: 2013

I  want to let someone to be able to publish his Infopath form templates developed partly with c# just on his own site collection;

I don't want the publisher user to have any access to other sites on the farm.

Is it possible in sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of box. with Csharp IP Form you need to upload and approve it via Central Admin.

Comment: any work around for the purpose?

Comment: not that i know of, but as it is on prem (almost)everything is possible, you would have to develop custom app/ web part that using service credentials would do same thing but without access to central admin.